# Google Fusion table Update SQL Query returns 400 ok Error

Tags: jquery, angularjs, rest, google-fusion-tables

Insert works fine but I am getting error with the Update and Delete code.

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql = UPDATE 1SubDA6g3Mz15DIHWpdec4iQ7sCV13aF7B94tJskK SET id = '2001' WHERE ROWID = "+pid+"&access_token="+$scope.Atoken
})
```

Error:

```
domain: "global",
reason: "required",
message: "Required parameter: sql", 
locationType: "parameter",
location: "sql"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces around the equals sign: "sql=" instead of "sql = ".

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution.

Solution:

```
$http({

method: "POST",

url: "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?
access_token="+$routeParams.token,

params: { 

         sql: "UPDATE 1R0f3qRr1Ew-V6rDcmZzrqEXxbCOit SET cId='"+answer.id+"',cName='"+answer.name+"',pass='"+answer.pass+"' WHERE ROWID ='"+detail.rId+"'"    
}

})
```